# iOS how to implement the official share function

Tags: ios, facebook, twitter, share, uiactivityviewcontroller

Include facebook, twitter, message, email and so on ,like this:

[image: iOS share function]

Answer (score 2):

In your ViewController.m :

```
NSString *message = @"The Flyer http://flyerdream.tumblr.com";
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"flyer"];
NSArray *arrayOfActivityItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:message, image, nil];
UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]
                                         initWithActivityItems:arrayOfActivityItems applicationActivities:nil];

[self.navigationController presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: I can see only message and email button! How can I get other social media buttons in Share sheet. Please help ...!! Thanks